# How to compile Haxe libraries to Javascript without enumerating every classes?

Tags: javascript, compilation, frameworks, haxe

I'm trying to make use of a Haxe library in Javascript. Since I already have a project written in Javascript, porting that to Haxe + using the given Haxe library isn't really a solution I'm ready to take at the moment.

Is there a way I can just compile the library from it's Haxe source folder to a JS file that I can then include in my `<script>` tags and refer to in my project? If I'm not mistaking, when a Haxe project normally compiles, it only includes the classes actually used in your project (correct?) - therefore I need some kind of tool or compiler options that will include all the classes in a given directory.

I would assume packages will get namespaced into Javascript objects at that point.

In case this helps, the library I'm looking to *transcompile* is Nape (Physics engine written in Haxe).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a way!

From FlashDevelop, create a new Haxe project (for JS).

Then, add a reference to the library that you wish to compile, either by:

- Finding it in your `Haxe install directory/haxe/lib/name_of_library/version_of_library`.
- Or, simply by adding the library name in your project settings, under **Libraries** (as shown in the picture below).

[image: screenshot of project settings for compiling Haxe to Javascript]

Third (most important step), add `--macro include('your_library_root_packagename')` in the Additional Compiler Options (replace with your library's top-level package name, obviously!)

I believe that if you have a library consisting of many top-level packages, you would need to enumerate several of those `--macro` compiler options. In my case I just needed the one.

Finally, **CTRL+ENTER**... wait for it to transcompile and Voila!

You have a Library in Javascript format!

Comment: Would like to give credits to this similar question on google-groups (Haxe to PHP): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/mAgQztsWo4M